# Why is underscore installed using npm or bower?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm very new to underscore, node, npm etc but I think I'm getting the hang of it.  However, I just went on to the underscore.js site to get a copy of it and I saw that there is an option to install via npm or bower.  Out of curiosity I ran the install in the rood directory of my project but nothing happened.  I'll just link to the underscore library in my index.html, so no worries there.  However I don't understand why it is even an option to install with npm.  Could someone kindly explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the case you want to require underscore for your server-side code. Then you can add it to your `package.json` just like any another dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing browser specific about underscore.js. There is an optional to install it via NPM because people use it with Node.js.

Bower, on the other hand, is a tool for managing client side JS dependancies for websites, so (assuming you are using it to manage your websites JS libraries) you can use it with your website.